# Java OpenGL draw offscreen buffer to image

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, off-screen

I'm trying to write a java opengl (JOGL) method that writes to an offscreen drawable and then writes that to an image. I have verified this works when using an onscreen drawable as well as GLP buffers, but the output image in its current state is just solid black. The code is below.

```
GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
caps.setOnscreen(false);

// create the offscreen drawable
GLDrawableFactory factory = GLDrawableFactory.getFactory(glp);
GLOffscreenAutoDrawable drawable = factory.createOffscreenAutoDrawable(null,caps,null,width,height);
drawable.display();
drawable.getContext().makeCurrent();

// a series of x/y coordinates
FloatBuffer buffer = generateData();

GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

// use pixel coordinates
gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();    
gl.glOrtho(0d, width, height, 0d, -1d, 1d);

// draw some points to the drawable
gl.glPointSize(4f);
gl.glColor3f(1f,0f,0f);    
gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, buffer);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL2.GL_POINTS, 0, numPoints);

BufferedImage im = new AWTGLReadBufferUtil(drawable.getGLProfile(), false).readPixelsToBufferedImage(drawable.getGL(), 0, 0, width, height, true /* awtOrientation */);
ImageIO.write(im,"png",new File("im.png"));
```

Comment: Have you looked at our Github project jogl-demos and our unit tests? GLPbuffer is deprecated as far as I know. Which version of JOGL do you use? Rather ask your question on the official forum and provide a complete source code that we can run: http://forum.jogamp.org Maybe there is a missing bind or something very trivial, I did a similar mistake some months ago.

Comment: Thanks. GLPBuffer is deprecated, but I was having trouble getting this to work with the createOffscreenDrawable. I'll post the example in the jogamp forums. Thanks.

Comment: We would be very happy if you posted here on our forum the working source code so that someone making a similar mistake can find the solution: http://forum.jogamp.org/Render-offscreen-buffer-to-image-td4032144.html

Comment: I will do that. Sorry I haven't quite done it yet...

Comment: Hi @JeffStorey, you should avoid legacy opengl

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but I found a solution to the problem that seems to work for me. I just added an ordinary `GLEventListener` object right before calling `.display()` on the drawable, as such:

```
//...
drawable.addGLEventListener(new OffscreenJOGL());
drawable.display();

//Move drawing code to OffscreenJOGL

BufferedImage im = new AWTGLReadBufferUtil(drawable.getGLProfile(), false).readPixelsToBufferedImage(drawable.getGL(), 0, 0, width, height, true /* awtOrientation */);
ImageIO.write(im,"png",new File("im.png"));
```

The code to draw now should be in your custom `OffscreenJOGL` class, under the `init(...)`, `reshape(...)` and `display(...)` methods. Note that setting the current context must be in the `init(...)` method of `OffscreenJOGL`. I get an exception thrown otherwise.

```
class OffscreenJOGL implements GLEventListener {
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        drawable.getContext().makeCurrent();
        //Other init code here
    }

    public void display(GLAutodrawable drawable) {
        //Code for drawing here
    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        //Called at least once after init(...) and before display(...)
    }

    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        //Dispose code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you might have found the required answer for your query.
If not, I suggest to add a line, for example:

```
gl.glClearColor(GLfloat red, GLfloat green, GLfloat blue, GLfloat alpha)
```

I have tested it, and it works.

Comment: please format your answer, and please don't add tag lines to your answer